# Making sticky work inside a div in UIKit v3

Tags: getuikit

In UIKit V3 I have the following which works fine with the div staying at the top (sticky) during scrolling:

**HTML**

```
<div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body" uk-sticky>Stick to the top</div>
<p>stuff</p>
<p>stuff</p>
<p>stuff</p>
<p>stuff</p>
<!-- [...] -->
```

[JSFiddle of the above](https://jsfiddle.net/g7poLj40/1/)

However, if I do the exact same thing within an `overflow-y: scroll;` div then the div just scrolls with the rest of the content rather than staying sticky:

**HTML**

```
<div id="thing" class="inline">
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body" uk-sticky>Stick to the top</div>
    <p>stuff</p>
    <p>stuff</p>
    <p>stuff</p>
    <p>stuff</p>
    <!-- [...] -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.inline {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[JSFiddle of the above](https://jsfiddle.net/vmyb7fau/2/)

I have tried using `uk-sticky="top: #thing"` but it doesn't make any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is more github issue. Also under the docs no example related to overflow box.

Answer (score 1):

The core javascript + all the tests her - without any example of sticky+overflow:

https://getuikit.com/docs/sticky

This is more a GitHub **Feature Request**. For now add `style="position: fixed;"` to solve this issue.

[Scrollable div content area with fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515103/scrollable-div-content-area-with-fixed-header)